# How can I stop multiple calls to a function inside an interval?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

How could I ensure that one one call of a function in an interval can run at once?

My code looks like this:

```
var promisePutTestQuestion;

   onEnter: ['$interval', 'questionService',
             ($interval, qus: IQuestionService) => {
      promisePutTestQuestion = $interval(() => {
         qus.putTestQuestionResponses();
      }, 5 * 1000);
   }],
   onExit: ['$interval',
            ($interval) => {
             $interval.cancel(promisePutTestQuestion);             
   }],
```

The problem I am having is if the putTestQuestionResponse (which returns a promise) is slow then I have multiple putTestQuestionResponse function calls one after the other.

Would appreciate if anyone has any ideas on this. Thanks

Comment: what `qus.putTestQuestionResponses` does?

Comment: It's a function that returns a promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript it's safe to use state variable for this purpose. Whenever `qus.putTestQuestionResponses` operation takes a lot of time next call will be skipped. So just maintain right state of processing variable, and if it's true quit the interval callback without running task again.

```
var promisePutTestQuestion;
let processing = false;

onEnter: ['$interval', 'questionService',
         ($interval, qus: IQuestionService) => {
  promisePutTestQuestion = $interval(() => {
     if (processing)
         return;
     processing = true;
     qus.putTestQuestionResponses()
     .then(() => processing = false)
  }, 5 * 1000);
}],
onExit: ['$interval', ($interval) => {
        $interval.cancel(promisePutTestQuestion);
}]
```

Not sure what promise framework you're using, but `() => processing = false` should be either in `finally()` for $q I guess, and in the `then` that should be after `catch` to ensure it is executed in any case.
So one of these:

```
qus.putTestQuestionResponses().finally(() => processing = false)
```

or

```
qus.putTestQuestionResponses().catch(...).then(() => processing = false)`
```

or even

```
qus.putTestQuestionResponses().then(() => processing = false).catch(() => processing = false)
```